# Set the default category of an attachment

Tags: categories, hooks, attachments

I wanted to apply the same categories that exist for posts to attachments, so I wrote this code:

```
function wpmediacategory_init() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpmediacategory_init' );
```

The problem I am having now is that behaviour is not quite like with posts. There a 2 features I would like to achieve:

1. When adding a new attachment, set it to "Uncategorized"
2. When updating an attachment, if it has no categories selected, set it to the "Uncategorized" category.

I have been trying to think what hooks I could be using, but without much success. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: "When changing an attachment categories, if it has none, set it to "Uncategorized"" - can you elaborate this line a little bit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem 1, you could hook to add_attachment and edit_attachment hook.

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'wpse_set_attachment_category');
add_action('edit_attachment', 'wpse_set_attachment_category');
function wpse_set_attachment_category( $post_ID )
{
    // if attachment already have categories, stop here
    if( wp_get_object_terms( $post_ID, 'category' ) )
        return;

    // no, then get the default one
    $post_category = array( get_option('default_category') );

    // then set category if default category is set on writting page
    if( $post_category )
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_category );
}
```